# regarding c++ pointer and physical memory

Tags: c++, memory

I have one clarification,

```
class Foo
{

}

main()   
{
   Foo obj; //1
   method(obj);
   method1(&obj);

   Foo* obj1;
   method2(&obj1);  //4

}

void method(Foo objfoo) //2
{

}

void method1(Foo* objfoo) //3
{

}

void method2(Foo* & objfoo){}
```

**Q1.** Will it allocates objects inside main stack frame ?

**Q2.** Will it create one more copy of Foo inside method stack frame ?

**Q3.** Will it point same object exists in obj present in main method ?

**Q4.** What this indicates ? need explanation ?

Comment: @Ademiban ,  need reason for closing this question. since i am beginner to c++ , need some confirmation on the above my questions for better understanding of memory model for c++ objects.

Comment: Every body will have their own clarification. It is not correct to expect questions of specific format.

Comment: when writing code use the "{}" icon to make your code print nicely (you need to select it first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are ordered by the Q1, Q2, etc., not the order they appear in the question.

1. Yes. (at least to the extent that there is a stack frame, or a stack).
2. Yes, at least in theory (in reality, the compiler may elide the copy though).
3. Yes, method1 receives a pointer to a pre-existing object.
4. It's passing the address of `obj1` to `method2`.

Aside: the call to `method2` mentioned in Q4 won't actually work. Since `obj1` is defined as a pointer to a `Foo`, and `method2` takes a reference to a pointer to a Foo, you would *not* need to (explicitly) take the address of the point to make the call. Doing so creates a pointer to a pointer, where `method2` needs a reference to a pointer. Using `method2(obj1);` would be at least syntactically correct (open to question whether it will really work correctly though).

Comment: I have one basic question... who is responsible for creating stack frame and loading function binaries from text area to stack frame ? when will it happen ?

Comment: @Muthu: The code to build/destroy stack frames will normally be compiled into the code (e.g., a function will start with something like `push bp/mov bp, sp/sub sp, frame_size` and end with something like `pop bp/ret`). Likewise for initializing local variables -- ctor invocation (for example) will be compiled into the binary.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: yes;

Q4: `&` means "address of". Taking the address of a pointer gives you a pointer to a pointer that is a `Foo**`.

Q2: Yes.

Q3: Yes.

`method2` : invalid, it should be

```
void method2(Foo** obj);
```

Comment: I have one basic question... who is responsible for creating stack frame and loading  function binaries from text area to stack frame ? when will it happen ?

Comment: The OS and the compiler are doing this for you. All your code is loaded before the process is started. The stack is changed when your function is called, that is in between the line where you call it and the first line of the function. You never have to worry about it.